# C# App - Video stream does not start at 1st attempt

Tags: c#, events, video, stream

My C# application starts minimised and shows the video stream of a webcam for 5 seconds when a certain event occurs. After that it is minimised again. This works well, but only from the 2nd event. On the first call, only an empty form is displayed.
Is there an event in which I can add a videoSourcePlayer1.Show() so that something is also displayed in the 1 event? It does nothing in the Form1_Shown event.

My code:

```
    ...
    private readonly UdpClient udp = new UdpClient(port);
    public IntPtr myHandle;

    public void wait(int milliseconds)
    {
      ...
    }

    private void StartListening()
    {
        this.udp.BeginReceive(Receive, new object());
    }

    private void Receive(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        IPEndPoint ip = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ip), port);
        byte[] bytes = udp.EndReceive(ar, ref ip);
        string message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
        if (message == "ON")
        {
            ShowWindow(myHandle, SW_RESTORE);
            Thread.Sleep(50);
            SetForegroundWindow(myHandle);
            wait(5000);
            ShowWindow(myHandle, SW_SHOWMINIMIZED);
        }
        StartListening();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myHandle = this.Handle;
        videoSourcePlayer1.VideoSource = new MJPEGStream("http://ip/video.mjpg");
        videoSourcePlayer1.Start();
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        StartListening();
    }


    private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
        {
            Hide();
            notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
            videoSourcePlayer1.Hide();
        }
        if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Normal)
        {
            Show();
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            notifyIcon1.Visible = false;
            videoSourcePlayer1.Show();
        }
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        videoSourcePlayer1.Stop();
    }

    private void notifyIcon1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Show();
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        notifyIcon1.Visible = false;
    }

}
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Got it. I changed the execution order in Form1_Resize and added a delay.

```
       if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Normal)
        {
            videoSourcePlayer1.Show();
            Thread.Sleep(250);
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            notifyIcon1.Visible = false;
            Show();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this method to continue the stream

```
 private void bntContinue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        videoSourcePlayer1.Continue();
    }
```

Comment: I don't want to click on the stream :-(

Comment: Instead of videoSourcePlayer1.Show(); change it to form2.show ( ); (the name of the form ) because it for moving from one form to another

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. I only have one form. Should I create a second one?